# Why is window.location.href appending url again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code, I'm assigning the following:

```
window.location.href = "www.example.com/test";
```

But when the page actually loads, the browser URL is `www.example.com/test/www.example.com/test`. I'm not appending anything to the URL, and I'm not sure how its appending the URL again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're missing the "http" or "https" part. Have you tried the following?

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/test";
```

**or**

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/test";
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you forgot the protocol. If you omit the protocol, `window.location.href` thinks you are trying to access a **folder** with the name of `www.example.com`, relative to the page you are currently on.

`window.location.href="http://www.example.com/test/"` will ensure that you access the external website `www.example.com`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Check the way you are constructing the url, sometimes we miss the host, or enter the incorrect path**

**A safe way to change the URl is by making changes in the exisiting URL**
first get the existing URL by

```
let exisitingURl = window.location.href;
```

now manipulate this url, for eg

```
exisitingURL = exisitingURL.replace('/auth', '/gateway');
```

now go to the url by

```
window.location.href = existingURL;
```