# window.location.replace returns incorrect link

Tags: javascript, django

I use `window.location.replace(qrMessage)` in my Django project, but it add the current page's URL before qrMessage into the searching page's URL and can't open it. Why does it happen and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to the original poster @iPzard - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333581/17651337)

I think you're missing the "http" or "https" part. Have you tried the following?

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/test";
```

or

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/test";
```